# Randomizing rows in a matrix but keeping groups together in R

Tags: r, random

I am trying to randomize a rather large matrix by row, however I need to keep same numbers in a particular column together.

For example:

```
# Table A
Column A       Column B
     0.1              1
     0.6              1
     1.5              1
      23              2
      18              2
     0.5              2
     0.6              3
      19              3
     0.7              3
```

My goal is to randomize by group, in this example by `Column B`. I have tried `sample.int(nrow(x))`, which worked fine to randomize all of the matrix, but is there a way to do this by group?

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: where column B would end up 222 333 111 (with its corresponding Column A values). I want to randomize the matrix (almost in chunks) based on the number in column B.

Comment: not necessarily 222 333 111, but randomly placed while keeping the same number together.

Answer (score 4):

A very straightforward approach would be to use "data.table", like this:

```
> library(data.table)
> as.data.table(mydf)[, .(Column_B = sample(Column_A)), by = Column_B]
   Column_B Column_B
1:        1      0.6
2:        1      1.5
3:        1      0.1
4:        2     23.0
5:        2     18.0
6:        2      0.5
7:        3      0.6
8:        3      0.7
9:        3     19.0
```

Or, more generally:

```
as.data.table(mydf)[, sample(.SD), by = Column_B]
```

Similarly, with "dplyr":

```
library(dplyr)

mydf %>%
  group_by(Column_B) %>%
  mutate(Column_A = sample(Column_A))
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  The data.table method works great for just those two columns.  However, I have a data table with 2500+ columns.  Is there a way to this with the entire table, based on column B?

Comment: @JC23, The approach at the other answer would work for that case without any modification.

Comment: @JC23, the `sample(.SD)` option that I shared (under "Or, more generally:") should also do what you're asking for. You can specify the columns to randomize using `.SDcols`. If that is omitted, it randomizes by everything not in the "`by = `" argument.

Answer (score 1):

Without conversion to data.frame/data.table and without external packages you could use `?ave` combined with `?sample`:

```
mymat[ave(seq_along(mymat[, "Col_A"]), mymat[, "Col_B"], FUN = sample),]
```

sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
mymat <- cbind(Col_A = rnorm(9), Col_B = rep(1:3, each = 3))
```

Comment: Your first part works and makes sense - but with your example: So I have 574 total entries, with my column B values ranging from 1-1150, with no consistency of the amount of each number. With your rnorm(x) function, would 574 go there? As for Col_B, with no way of knowing the amount of reps - is it still possible to do it your way?

Comment: @jC23, you don't need to care about the sample data - I only generate it only for demonstration purposes. You can just adapt the code in my answer with the name and column names of your real data.

Comment: Right, but that gives me my original table.  How do I then randomize by group("column B")?  Thanks.

Comment: @JC23, did you assign the Output? I.e. `mymat <- mymat[...]`?

Comment: Yes - *allC5<-allC5[ave(seq_along(allC5[,"Ctot"], allC5[, "pedon_key"], FUN = sample),]* gave me back the same table I had.  Getting rid of the column A term (Ctot) *allC5<-allC5[ave(seq_along(allC5[, "pedon_key"]), FUN = sample),]* Did get the table to randomize, but did not keep profiles #s (Column B) together.